# Selecting and launching shortcuts from a non-launcher app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, shortcut

What I would like to do is the following:

1. User selects a shortcut from a list of all available shortcuts in the system;
2. The relevant info is stored;
3. User performs an action and the selected shortcut is executed, like if it was an icon on the home screen.

So far I am able to populate and present a list with all the shortcuts, using 
`getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT), 0);`. Upon selecting a shortcut, I start the `ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT` intent to customize the shortcut parameters - it presents the proper UI and seems to work. I use this code to start the intent:

```
ActivityInfo activity = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
i.setComponent(name);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Here is my onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode==1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                startActivity((Intent) data.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT));
            } catch (Exception e) {             
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail: "+resultCode+" "+resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Now, the problem is that the `onActivityResult` always gets triggered immediately after `startActivityForResult` with requestCode=0, resultCode=0 and with no data. It does not trigger when the `ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT` activity actually ends. I really don't get it. I think that after the activity ends it should return the requestCode I sent it and the data intent, containing the `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT` which I could then use ***somehow*** to actually start the shortcut.

The second part of the question is how do I actually store the necessary information for the shortcut the user selected, preferably in `SharedPreferences`, so I could later execute this shortcut with the specific parameters. I couldn't find any example of this.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More then 2 years later, here is the answer to my question:

The proper functioning of the `startActivityForResult`/`onActivityResult` system obviously depends on both the calling and the called Activities being part of the same Task. Therefore ***any*** action which would cause the two activities to be launched in separate Tasks would break this functionality. Such actions include setting any exclusive `launchMode` for any of the Activities in the `AndroidManifest.xml` or using flags such as `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when launching any of the two Activities.

Upvoted the answer of user2427931 for the `Intent.parseUri()` solution.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you please update your question with the code that you've found to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same behavior when my calling activity had launchMode="singleInstance". Do you have that defined as well?

Regarding saving the Intents. You could turn the intent into an URI and save it as a string in SharedPreferences. You could then use Intent.pareseUri() once you have retrieved it.

//Erty